# My royal Enfield classic 350 is not accelerating upto full throttle

Tags: throttle, royal-enfield

My royal Enfield classic 350 is not accelerating upto full throttle..... As we give acceleration in every gear it's acceleration is going till half throttle... From there it's not accelerating and bike speed is not increasing....

Comment: Have you checked the air filter?

Comment: Clogged carburetor main jet?